# Updating a PyQt Widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have a Python program to plot a simple graph in using a custom matplotlib widget.
My code is as follows:

```
import sys
from GUI import *
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class GUIForm(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,
                               QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.PlotFunc)

    def PlotFunc(self):
        randValList = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)
        print(randValList)
        self.ui.PlotWidget.canvas.ax.clear()
        self.ui.PlotWidget.canvas.ax.plot(randValList)

    def callFunc(self):
        myapp.PlotFunc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = GUIForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the program I can see the GUI but when I click the button the plot does not show the line. The empty plot is visible.
However if I dO

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
            self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,
                                   QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.PlotFunc)
            self.ui.PlotWidget.canvas.ax.plot(randValList)
```

or

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = GUIForm()
        myapp.show()
        self.PlotFunc()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the program draws the graph.
So I'm guessing it has to do with `sys.exit(app.exec_())` but do not know how to fix this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please confirm the name of your button instance? In your connect function you specify `self.ui.pushButton`. Usually Designer creates them with `self.pushButton` as default.

Comment: @dex19dt thank you. It is self.ui because button is part of the Ui_Dialog.

Comment: Does your print statement show when you click the button? Have you confirmed that the signal is firing at least?

Comment: @jdi Thank you jdi. Yes I can see the print statement working. Random values are printed everytime I click the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By any chance, does it work if you add this line at the end of PlotFunc?

```
self.ui.PlotWidget.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it did work. I didn't know that I need to call draw() on the canvas each time I draw something. I thought app_exec() runs a loop that detects each input and then automatically draws. Thank you!

Comment: I found the window has a `repaint()` method, no arguments. Thank you all.